# com/android/jill/api/ConfigNotSupportedException in android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android-studio-2.3

When i build the project in android 2.3.2 i see an error like this :
Error:Execution failed for task 'compileReleaseRenderscript'.

> com/android/jill/api/ConfigNotSupportedException

In my earlier version of android studio (1.5) same source  worked fine. Any idea what could be the reason

Comment: should i try a lower android studio version for it to work ?

Comment: have you find any fixes?